# Making ALT image text display on load and not just click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript code is set to show ALT images text in a div on clicking the image. I would like it to show the first image text on load. Right now the div is blank on page load.

I tried setting the the first image as "active" but that did not work on load. I tried to use an OnLoad click function on load which also failed.

```js
var myImage = document.getElementsByClassName("lazyload");
var text = document.getElementById("show");

for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
    myImage[i].addEventListener('click',show);
}

function show(){
  var myAlt = this.alt;
  text.innerHTML = myAlt;
}
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

This works on click, but not sure how to make it display when the webpage loads.

Comment: alt text is there to show if the image doesn't show?. Could you add your html code btw

Comment: The div: div<div id="show"></div>
The Img tag: <img class="lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="https://some-image.jpg" alt="Shown in Satin Nickel with Red Cord"

Comment: you must have some images too and some html with the classname 'lazyload'. Edit the snippet